Instant checkmate publishing old information
I had been removed from a sex offender registry years ago. A site called InstantCheckmate is still publishing my address and information as a registered sex offender. They claim their “policy” is they publish current and “historic” information. There is no way this can be legal. Any advice appreciated. They claim they will remove it if I provide documentation. I shouldn’t have to.

What is the jurisdiction? IANAL, but I don't think this would be illegal in the US.

In the US, truth is generally a valid defense to defamation. If they're clear that they include historical information, and you were indeed on the registry in the past, then it's true.

Were you removed because you were exonerated, or because you served the sentence and a registration time limit was reached? I suspect they want proof of the former to remove you from the historical record.

united-states
If the information is identified as "historic" it is almost surely legal. It was a true statement of fact at one time and there is not a representation that you are currently on the registry. Since it is true, it is not defamatory. And, once information is disclosed the law can't put the "genie back into the bottle."
